# Query to get SSRS report parameters and Drop Down options slow

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I need to get a list of parameters for a specific SSRS report and show all the possible drop down items available (along with Report parameter name, DataType, and Prompt).

I'm not sure of other options (if there are any). The query returns exactly what I need, it just takes too long to be useful (10-12 seconds). Is there another way to get these results or make this one faster?

```
USE ReportServer
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(25)
SET @dbname='DBName'
DECLARE @rptlistStr VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @reportlist table ( path varchar(500), name varchar(500) )
insert into @reportlist
exec [ADA Master].[dbo].[spGetAdminReports] @dbname

set @rptlistStr = substring((SELECT ( ', ' + Name ) FROM @reportlist WHERE NAME = 'rptReport'
FOR XML PATH( '' )
), 3, 1000 )          


SELECT NAME, PATH,
y.r.query ('for $s in *:ParameterValue/*:Value return concat(data($s),"|")') [DropDownItemValue]    
, y.r.query ('for $s in *:ParameterValue/*:Label return concat(data($s),"|")') [DropDownItemLabel]      
, x.r.value ('@Name', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ReportParameterName
, x.r.value ('*:DataType[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS DataType
, x.r.value ('*:AllowBlank[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS AllowBlank
, x.r.value ('*:Prompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Prompt
, x.r.value ('*:Hidden[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Hidden
, x.r.value ('*:MultiValue[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS MultiValue
FROM (
SELECT  PATH
, NAME
, CAST(CAST(content AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS XML) AS ReportXML 
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog 
join master.dbo.ufn_SplitStringArray(@rptlistStr,',') a on NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = a.Item COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE CONTENT IS NOT NULL AND TYPE = 2
) C
CROSS APPLY C.ReportXML.nodes('*:Report/*:ReportParameters/*:ReportParameter') x(r) 
OUTER APPLY x.r.nodes('*:ValidValues/*:ParameterValues') y(r) 
where x.r.value ('*:Prompt[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') is not null
```

Comment: Why are you putting the list of reports into a comma separated value into rptlistStr and then splitting it again in your join? maybe look at just doing a join to your reportlist table. Also you're filtering your results into rptlistStr for 1 report called 'rptReport'?    Are you calling a stored procedure to get a list of reports, but then only filtering it to 1 report into a comma separated value then then re-splitting that value in your join?   Just trying to better understand what's going.  Why call [spGetAdminReports] then?

Comment: You're right, I initially was getting the list of all the reports - then changed my strategy and forgot to remove it.  But, in removing it there is no difference in query run time.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost - I would not query ReportServer.dbo.Catalog directly; people do this all the time and it's crazy. Converting img data into VARNBINARY(MAX) then into XML is insanely expensive. ***If you need this information often I suggest dumping the results of this query into another table*** (we'll call it "SSRS_RDL") then, as part of your Report Deployment process you would update SSRS_RDL with changes and new records as needed. Even an hourly job that does this will often be enough. This way you're dealing with relational data that is easy to index and can be retreived 1000's of times faster than how you are doing it now.

That said you have a serious design flaw with your code; you are:

1. executing [ADA Master].[dbo].[spGetAdminReports] to push rows into your @reportlist table
2. then using XML PATH to turn @reportlist into a string called @rptlistStr
3. Then using dbo.ufn_SplitStringArray to turn @rptlistStr back into a table
4. Joining the results of this table to ReportServer.dbo.Catalog

You can get rid of `@rptlistStr` and the code to populate it from @reportList, and instead join your @reportlist table to ReportServer.dbo.Catalog. In other words, change:

```
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog AS c
JOIN master.dbo.ufn_SplitStringArray(@rptlistStr,',') a on NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = a.Item COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

To:

```
FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog AS c
JOIN @reportlist AS a ON on c.Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = a.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Lastly:

This query will run much faster with a parallel execution plan. Once you've made the changes I just outline consider using `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649)` at the end of your final SELECT query (or using Make_Parallel() by Adam Machanic.)

Comment: I took out #1,2,3 of your list (not needed- something I should have removed before I posted this).  (query runs in the exact same amount of time).  I also added the "OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649)" - not sure exactly what that does yet.  (and not sure how to use Make_Parallel() yet)

Comment: I am going to take your suggestion of outputting the results to a table and schedule a job to run daily.  We don't change parameters very often.  I thought there may have been another way (place I could get the info I needed) without even having to parse XML.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is my first post, is there something I need to do to set your answer as "the answer"?

Comment: Haha - I have never asked a question here so I had to Google it. There should be a checkbox: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hm... maybe I accidentally did it somehow... I see it says "1 Answer"... but I think it said that the second it was posted.  It is the answer... I looked at the instructions and it says you can "Vote up" and "vote down" and unaccept answer but - I don't see any of those options.  Thanks again for your help!